# How to resolve moodle Failure Signing Data: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt - SHA256?

Tags: ssl, single-sign-on, moodle, saml-2.0

I am developing a Moodle website using SSO. I have configured auth_saml2 moodle plugin and I have tested with test login.  I am getting error

> Exception: Failure Signing Data: error: 06065064: digital envelope routines: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex: bad decrypt - SHA256

I have tried SHA384, SHA512 algorith but still am getting same error.

Error screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error message has been reported on Github in a couple of tickets.

https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_saml2/issues/387

https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_saml2/issues/380

Looks like the certificate might need to be regenerated?

Also a post on Moodle, they switched to OpenID

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=397317

Comment: Hi Russell Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

The certificate needs to be regenerated, from the saml settings click the 'Regenerate certificate' button, or go here:

http://moodle.example/auth/saml2/regenerate.php

and resave the certificate. You will need to re-import the SP metadata again with your IdP.